# Background Task WP8 - Access to isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, offline

I am trying to access the files on my windows phone's storage. I know that they are completely independent of each other as one is a windows phone app and the other is windows runtime component.

```
  public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        BackgroundTaskDeferral _defferal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Starting Offline Functionality");

        _defferal.Complete();
    }
```

This method runs when the network state is changed. From here i want to access the phones storage.
has anyone done this before, or can think of any work arounds?

I am running visual studio 2012 with windows phone 8.1

Comment: You can surely access *LocalFolder* in *BackgroundTask*. [Here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx) you should find some help.

Comment: yes, your right. was trying to access the wrong thing. Thanks!

Comment: Note that Romasz's link is for runtime apps. The basics are the same for Silverlight apps, but some of the details are different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Using isolated storage is the recommended way to pass data between the background task and the foreground app. You can use a mutex, to prevent the two processes from interfering with each other if they both end up running at the same time.

See MSDN's [Communication between foreground app and background agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202944(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_CommunicationBetweenForegroundApplicationandBackgroundAgent) and Quickstart: [Working with files and folders in Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: I think the OP mixed WP8.0, 8.1 and BackgroundTask. Nevertheless answer for both is the same (+1). You have missed the letter 'x' in *mutex*. I also don't know if you have something against me correcting formatting of your answer.

Comment: Thanks. Typo fixed (I was bit by autocorrect: I'll add mutex to my dictionary!). In the future please feel free to fix typos as needed.